# Animation time does not work

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code for a `footer` section - so when I mouse hover on the footer the footer's height increases and the above `div` decreases a bit

But I want that to happen over a few seconds, but my code does not work.

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('footer').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).css({height:"100px"},5000);
       $(".whyUs").css({height:"450px"},5000);
    });
    $('footer').mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).css({height: '50px'},5000); 
       $(".whyUs").css({height:"500px"},5000);
       $("#fimg").css({display: "none"});
    });
});
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CSS3 `transition` to the rescue

To keep jQ's `.css()` method, simply add i.e: `transition: 1s;` (or use *ms* values) to the element you want to see animated.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kuvayi/2/edit?html,css,js,output)***

---

### jQuery `.animate()` method

You cannot animate `.css()` (unless you set i.e: `transition: 1s;` in CSS!) but `.animate()`

```
$(this).animate({height: 100}, 5000);
//      ^^^^^^^ instead of .css
```

Also there's no need to set `"px"`, px are default in jQuery, use just the value.
Also to prevent animation buildups on fast enter/leave use `.stop()`

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured

   var $whyUs = $(".whyUs"); // Cache your selectors
   var $fimg  = $("#fimg");

   $('footer').hover(function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({height: 100}, 5000);
       $whyUs.stop().animate({height:450}, 5000);
       // what about using $fimg.css({display: "block"}); ?
   }, function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({height: 50}, 5000); 
       $whyUs.stop().animate({height:500}, 5000);
       $fimg.css({display: "none"});
   });

});
```

or if you are familiar with the Ternary Operator `?:`

```
   $('footer').hover(function( e ) {
       var mE = e.type==="mouseenter";
       $(this).stop().animate({height: mE ? 100 : 50}, 5000);
       $whyUs.stop().animate({height: mE ? 450 : 500}, 5000);
       // what about using $fimg.css({display: mE ? "block" : "none"}); ?
   });
```

Comment: true, unless you had a css `transition:height 500ms ease;` on it

Comment: @zgood I guess you could say that you cannot use $.css() to control animations